# Why is AWS CloudFormer so slow even if i beef up the underlying instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

[Using CloudFormer to Create AWS CloudFormation Templates from Existing AWS Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) is a resource that I hoped to use to take frequent and scheduled infrastructure snapshots as a mechanism for "Disaster Recovery".

The cloudformer tool is a web-based app that is spun up as an EC2 instance by an AWS Cloudformation canned template.

It takes upto 20-30 minutes to create a template file that contains all the AWS resources in my account. **Why?**

I have tried increasing the instance size from a t2.small to a **m5.4xlarge** and there is only marginal performance improvement.

Is it because the cloudformer tool makes a ton of calls to aws-cli and these calls are somehow throttled by AWS?

Any alternatives to automate taking scheduled snapshots of AWS infrastructure that can be fed into Cloud Formation for quick recovery?

Thanks!